# Spring Security permitAll for root but protect everything else

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to allow access to / for everybody but restrict all other paths

Something like

```
.antMatchers("/").permitAll()
.antMatchers("NOT /").authenticated()
```

How do I have to set the pattern for "NOT /"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.antMatchers("/").permitAll()
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

`permitAll()` will only be applied to requests matching `"/"`, other requests will be routed further to `authenticated()`.